# Quit() Button not working after converting to application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a simple GUI in Tkinter and tried to convert it into an application. There is a manually made exit button in the program that works when it is a python program but not when made into an application. My code is:

```
def exit():
    quit()
def main():

    root = tk.Tk()

    top = Frame(root)
    bottom = Frame(root)

    top.config(bg="lightgray")
    top.pack(side=TOP)

    bottom.config(bg="gray")
    bottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    root.title("Quote of the Day")
    root.overrideredirect(True)

    root.lift()
    root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.8)
    root.iconbitmap("icon.png")

    b1 = Button(root,text = " X ",  command = exit, bg = None)
    b1.config(width = 1, height = 1, borderwidth = 0)

    b1.pack(in_=top, side=RIGHT)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__==('__main__'):
    main()
```

Comment: `command=root.destroy` might work better.  I believe `quit()` is primarily intended for interactive use.

Comment: Yeah it does. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an example using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is _incomplete_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting command of the button to call exit , just use `root.destroy`.

So , you'll have to modify the button declaration line as:

```
b1 = Button(root,text = " X ",  command = root.destroy, bg = None)
```